# How to use a hash function in arduino

Tags: hash, arduino, sha1

I am developing a project with arduino and I want to use a hash function on the data generated by a temperature sensor?

To be more specific I want to use the SHA-1 hash.

Comment: So the problem is what exactly? It seems to me you just need to find some freely usable SHA1 C/C++ code on the net and compile it for the Arduino.

Comment: I just need to get a numeric value from a sensor and generate the hash of this value and send that hash to the web.

Answer (score 0):

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1 and you notice, an 8-bit controller which stores integers in LittleEndian is not the optimal platform for your idea.
The available RAM (2kB) of an atmega328 should be sufficient, if you do not need too much RAM for the raw data.

So, have fun ;)

My main concern is rather the "why"?

What's wrong with a CRC checksum or similar, or a eventually a private hash algorithm, to ensure data integrity?

Comment: I just need to get a numeric value from a sensor and generate the hash of this value and send it to the web.

Comment: What do you mean by "the hash" of a numeric value? In my understanding a hash serves to condense something big to something smaller, but still unique, to identify the big thing, e.g. to ensure its integrity. SHA-1 produces a 20 byte hash number, to identify series of blocks of 64 bytes. "A numeric value from a sensor", smaller than 20 byte, is better transferred as it is ;)

Comment: My concern is not to transmit the value so that invaders could see this value. I just need to get a numerical value and generate the hash of this value.

Comment: So you want to (ab)use SHA-1 as an encryption method?
And how do you want to decrypt it?

Comment: I'm developing a technique that can solve this. My problem is how to use SHA-1 on arduino

Comment: It's not a problem to implement an SHA-1 hash algorithm on an 8bit arduino. But you cannot use that seriously for encryption/decryption tasks. A hash is to ensure data integrity. You get data and its hash value and can check if they meet. But you cannot create false data that fits to a given hash value.